# /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found

Tags: c++

I have a problem. When I run C++ application, I get this error:

./MCServer: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by ./MCServer)

./MCServer: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by ./MCServer)

How to fix it? What packages want to install?

Comment: I use a Centos 7 64 bit

Comment: We need more informations: compiler? kind of program? compiler options used?

Comment: CentOS 7's libstdc++ only supports upto `GLIBCXX_3.4.13`.

Comment: How do I get this information, which teams perform?

Answer (score 2):

Your application `MCServer` was compiled and linked with different g++ than current for your OS, and ABI is not compatible. You either need to find libstdc++.so.6 for original compiler and set environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` accordingly or recompile the app with compiler, that comes with your OS.

Comment: You can more detailed instructions, please?

Comment: @Andrew I do not have enough information from you to provide more detailed instructions.

Comment: How do I get this information, which teams perform?

Comment: @Andrew I can help you in chat but only in 3-4 hours. I do not have access to chat right now. Btw commands not teams.

Comment: do you have skype, icq?

Comment: @Andrew I do but I cannot access them from work either.

Comment: helping in chat does not help future visitors to this question :-(

Answer (score 1):

[@Slava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/432358/slava)'s answer is abstract and identifies the reason of failure. 
However it contains no practical ways of getting the right lib.

[@Rizwan Javid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5629062/rizwan-javid) offered such way, but a binary blob placed on a random github page may not seem secure enough for some people. Hence my try to add some more info + another source of `libstdc++.so.6.0.2x`

As [FoldingAtHome/fah-issues](https://github.com/FoldingAtHome/fah-issues/issues/1147#issuecomment-134731211) writes:

[image]

... these are suitable versions:
`libstdc++.so.6.0.20`,
`libstdc++.so.6.0.21`

And here comes another such lib in `chrome-deps-stable` package from the repository of [Nux Dextop for CentOS 6](https://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el6/x86_64/chrome-deps-stable-3.11-1.x86_64.rpm):

```
$ objdump -p /opt/google/chrome/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | egrep '^[0-9].*(GLIBCXX_3.4.2.|CXXABI_1.3.8)'
22 0x00 0x0297f870 GLIBCXX_3.4.20
23 0x00 0x0297f871 GLIBCXX_3.4.21
32 0x00 0x0bafd178 CXXABI_1.3.8
```

([the source](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/nux-dextop-x86_64/chrome-deps-stable-3.11-1.x86_64.rpm.html))

At least it works on my CentOS 7.6 box:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/google/chrome/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

And now Viber runs fine here.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is specific to RHEL-7.3 as i have reproduced this error on same:-
Reason is `libstdc++.so.6` is not pointing towards the required `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` which is `libstdc++.so.6.0.20`. so you need to upload `libstdc++.so.6.0.20` to your `/lib64/` directory:-
Steps to follow:-

1. Download  `libstdc++.so.6.0.20` from https://github.com/DevopsRizwan/requiredlibbin.git

   2. `scp libstdc++.so.6.0.20 root@vmname:/lib64/
   3. check the sym link of `ls -l libstdc++.so.6` it will be pointing to otherthan `libstdc++.so.6.0.20`
   4. unlink the symlink `unlink libstdc++.so.6`
   5. Again create the sym link to correct lib and in this case it is `ln -s  libstdc++.so.6.0.20  libstdc++.so.6`
   6. By now you will be able to see that the new symlink points to required lib, check by `ls -l libstdc++.so.6`  it should be `libstdc+.so.6 -> libstdc+.so.6.0.20`

P.S. Tested on Rhel7.3*

Comment: we need version libstdc++.so.6.0.222 and couldnt find any package . because our server is not connected to internet and using redhat 7.9